# помогите разобраться с выводом nodejs express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Появилась новая проблема. Сброшу только код сервера и всех `.ejs` - файлов.
Проблема в том, что данные картинки не отображаются теперь на странице поста!Я просто не совсем понимаю, как использовать 1 файл в разных местах, может лучше создать отдельно другой шаблон, что бы небыль таких проблем? Я думаю проблемы уйдут почти все сразу!

Сервер находится в корне. 
Все фалды `.ejs` - находятся в `/views/` (кроме последнего, его место расположения `/views/blocks/post.ejs`)

server.js -->

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
var db = require('./db');

var app = express();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
var obj = [
  {
    title: "What about my Blog",
    id: 1,
    url: "http://nabeel.co.in/files/bootsnipp/gallery/1.jpg",
    description: 'Now i want to tell you something...'
  },
  {
    title: "What about my Blog",
    id: 2,
    url: "http://nabeel.co.in/files/bootsnipp/gallery/2.jpg",
    description: 'Now i want to tell you something...'
  },
  {
    title: "What about my Blog",
    id: 3,
    url: "http://nabeel.co.in/files/bootsnipp/gallery/3.jpg",
    description: 'Now i want to tell you something...'
  }
];
console.log(obj[0].url);
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use("/public", express.static("public"));

// Home Page Getting
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home', {obj: obj});
});

//About Page Getting
app.get('/about', function(req, res){
  res.render('about');
});
//Post ID
app.get('/post/:id', function(req, res){
  res.render('post-page', {postId: req.param.id, item: obj});
});
//About Page Getting
app.get('/contact', function(req, res){
  res.render('contact');
});
// Error 404 Page
app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.render("404");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

home.ejs -->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pavel's Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header id="header__main">
      <% include blocks/navigation.ejs %>
    </header>
    <section id="posts">
      <div class="container gal-container">
        <div class="row">
          <% obj.forEach(function(item){ %>
                    <% include blocks/post.ejs %>
                <% }); %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <% include blocks/footer.ejs %>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

post-page.ejs -->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pavel's Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header id="header__main">
      <% include blocks/navigation.ejs %>
    </header>
    <section id="posts">
      <div class="container gal-container">
        <h1><%= item.title %></h1>
        <% include blocks/post.ejs %>
        <p><%= item.description %></p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <% include blocks/footer.ejs %>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

ну и сам post.ejs -->

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 co-12 gal-item">
  <div class="box">
    <a href="/post/<%= item.id %>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<%= item.id %>">
      <img src="<%= item.url %>">
    </a>
    <div class="modal fade" id="8" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <img src="<%= item.url %>">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 description">
            <h4>This is the eighth one on my Gallery</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если что, проблема заключается в последней части кода - именно там не реагирует на значения вывода, а так-же в инспекторе кода html показывает пустой атрибут.

Comment: Давайте вопросам нормальные названия плиз.

Comment: @Kromster забыл удалить комментарии, не решил я проблему, сейчас пытаюсь решить

Comment: я правильно вас понял, что при переходе по данному УРЛу `/post/:id` у Вас ничего не отображается

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев у меня как бы выводит шаблон, но нет ни самой фотографии, ни заголовков которые в шаблоне post-page.ejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы передаете в шаблон весь объект постов, а нужно только нужный Вам пост согласно его id. Для этого используемся filter.

```js
var obj = [
  {
    title: "What about my Blog",
    id: 1,
    url: "http://nabeel.co.in/files/bootsnipp/gallery/1.jpg",
    description: 'Now i want to tell you something...'
  },
  {
    title: "What about my Blog",
    id: 2,
    url: "http://nabeel.co.in/files/bootsnipp/gallery/2.jpg",
    description: 'Now i want to tell you something...'
  },
  {
    title: "What about my Blog",
    id: 3,
    url: "http://nabeel.co.in/files/bootsnipp/gallery/3.jpg",
    description: 'Now i want to tell you something...'
  }
];
let = need_id = 2; //искомый id 
let find = obj.filter(item => {return (item.id == need_id)? item: false});
console.log(find);
```

Ваш route будет выглядеть так

```js
app.get('/post/:id', function(req, res){
  let post = obj.filter(item => {return (item.id == req.params.id)? item: false})[0];

  res.render('post-page', {postId: req.params.id, item: post});
});
```

Comment: `req.params.id` - скорее всего так, а во вторых, нет, не помогло, все точно так же выглядит(

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич  ну я данный код копировал у Вас. Сделайте `console.log(post);` и смотрите что хрониться в переменной.

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич я обновил код для вашего `route`, `filter` возвращает массив, а нам нужен объект. Так как мы знаем, что массив будем из одного элемента то в конце можно просто добавить `[0]`

Comment: `obj.filter(item => {return (item.id == req.params.id)? item: false})[0]` -> `obj.find(item => item.id == req.params.id);` [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо. буду знать

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, скажите а что нужно сделать ещё что бы добавить, что если нет такого поста, то вернуть error

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич добавьте условие. если в post будет undefined тогда рендери страницу с ошибкой